# Not sure if my calculation is correct, can anyone check this RC circuit for me?

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, circuit-analysis

[image: Circuit] Hello everyone, so in my book I decided to do this practice question but failed to notice that the answer was not given in the back of the book. If anyone can help me confirm my answer I would much appreciate it.

The problem asks me to find the current over the 5 ohm resistor as a function of time.
The initial condition is that the capacitor is charged to 5 volts. Top of the capacitor is positive polarity bottom is negative; should have put the signs in.

The answer I got to was the following:

$$
i_{R_{(5\Omega)}}(t)=\frac{(20sin(4t))}{(241)} + \frac{75cos(4t)}{241} + \frac{10}{3} - 2.6445e^{(-15t)}
$$

If the formatting of this post is all wrong please forgive me. This is the first post I've ever made on a stackexchange site!

[The INCORRECT Work I did to get to the answer above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TOBx.jpg)

### ANSWER

The question has been answered thanks to a reddit user!

[Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/EngineeringStudents/comments/2c59rf/can_anyone_confirm_my_work/) is a link to the reddit post.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByRE8.jpg) is a direct link to their solution.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce8yn.jpg) is a direct link to the corrections I did to my work (marked in red).

Hope this helps anyone in the future!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Answered thanks to a user on reddit!](http://www.reddit.com/r/EngineeringStudents/comments/2c59rf/can_anyone_confirm_my_work/cjcskfc)
[image]